# Passing a database value to a front-end querystring

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, query-string

This may be a simple question, but I'm trying to call a a value from table in my back-end SQL Server database and pass it through a querystring in the URL.  For example:

I'm building a mobile web site that registers a mobile device to an account on the sign up page.  After the database entry is created, I want the to get the generated deviceId from the database and pass it to a querystring in the URL such as: http://www.mobilewebsite.com?dId=22

Is this easily possible, or is it even the best solution for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something more unique to the device be more appropriate? Such as it's ESN?

Why not generate a GUID on the device and simply submit that. That way, no round trip to the database is required.

Comment: Is it a device ID or a registrant ID?

Comment: It's a device Id for a mobile device.  How would I be able to go about doing this?